# Issue with Programming word 2013 : " ComException Occurred"

Tags: vb.net, office-2013

I have a piece of code written in vb.net which is working fine with word 2007..
but same code is throwing error when run on system with office 2013..
my code are below.

OWDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText:="DATE:", Format:=True, Forward:=True)

and I get the below error ..
**ComException Occurred**
This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading.

thanks in Advance...

Comment: Are you really using vb.net or your code is part of a vba macro? In this case you need to change the question tag

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/2013/02/22/word2013bug-not-available-for-reading/

Comment: thanks... My issue was resolved...